# R: rJava error with xlsx (0.4.2) package

Tags: r, apache-poi, xlsx, rjava

I am trying to use the xlsx package to fill a spreadsheet with information from an external file. Up until now, I have used addDataFrame() to put information into the spreadsheet, and everything about it that I have tried has been successful (fonts, colors, borders, etc.)

The issue now is that I need to have a column of hyperlinks, and to do that I need to get or create the specific cells (I'm not sure which, and both give the same error). The following code:

```
library(xlsx)
wb = createWorkbook(type="xlsx")
sheet = createSheet(wb, sheetName="InProduction")
createCell(1, 2)
```

Produces the error:

> Error in .jcall(row[[ir]], "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell;",
>   "createCell",  :    RcallMethod: cannot determine object class

After doing some poking around, I found the method it is trying to call is [from this API](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getFirstCellNum%28%29) with the call:

```
minColIx <- .jcall(row[[ir]], "T", "getFirstCellNum")
```

Which seems to me like it ought to work, but it clearly doesn't. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create rows using `createRow` or `getRows` before you can create cells in these rows using `createCells`.