# Can someone help me about this error? I am trying to import data frame from html page in Excel file

Tags: javascript, r, xlsx, r-xlsx

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(x = link.table, file = "actual1.xlsx",sheetName = "TestSheet", row.names = FALSE)
save(link.table,file="actual.Rda")
```

I get this output:

> library(xlsx)
>
> write.xlsx(x = link.table, file = "actual1.xlsx",sheetName ="TestSheet", row.names = FALSE)
> Error in .jcall(row[[ir]], "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell;", "createCell", : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column index (-1). Allowable column range for EXCEL2007 is (0..16383) or ('A'..'XFD')

Comment: Help is provided here in this stack overflow link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300647/r-rjava-error-with-xlsx-0-4-2-package